How to fix days to next birthday calculation error in python program
I have to write a python program to calculate on which day a birthday is and how many days it takes to the next birthday. The program seems to be working most of the time, but sometimes it calculates that it will take too many days. For example: it's currently October the 11th and it is 255 days till June the 23th, but the program says it will take 259.
I already tried asking ai and searching on the internet, but I couldn't find anything online and chatgpt gave me code that didn't work.
Here is my code:

year = 0
month = 0
day = 0
birthday_year = 0
birthday_month = 0
birthday_day = 0

#Quick way to add blank line
def blank_line(stripes):
    if stripes == 0:
        stripes = 55
    print(stripes * "-")

#Lists for showing what day/month it is.
weekdays = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]
months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

days_per_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def is_leap_year(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

def days_in_month(month, year):
    if month == 2 and is_leap_year(year) == True:
        return 29
    else:
        return days_per_month[month - 1]

def day_of_the_week(day, month, year):
    if month < 3:
        month = month + 12
        year = year - 1
    k = year % 100
    j = year // 100
    f = day + ((13 * (month + 1)) // 5) + k + (k // 4) + (j // 4) - (2 * j)
    return weekdays[f % 7 - 2]

def calculate_age(birthday_day, birthday_month, birthday_year, current_day, current_month, current_year):
    age_age = current_year - birthday_year
    if (birthday_month > current_month) or (birthday_month == current_month and birthday_day > current_day):
        age_age = age_age - 1
    return age_age

def days_till_next_birthday(birthday_day, birthday_month, current_day, current_month, current_year):
    #Calculates days till next birthday
    if birthday_day >= current_day and birthday_month == current_month:
        days_till = birthday_day - current_day

    elif birthday_month > current_month:
        days_till = days_in_month(current_month, current_year) - current_day
        months_until_birthday = birthday_month - current_month
        for run in range(months_until_birthday - 1):
            run_month = current_month + (run + 1)
            print("run month debug:", run_month)
            days_until_quick_debug = days_till
            days_till = days_till + days_in_month(run_month, current_year)
            print("days in month debug", days_till - days_until_quick_debug)
            print("days until debug", days_till)
        days_till = days_till + birthday_day

    elif birthday_month < current_month:
        days_till = days_in_month(current_month, current_year) - current_day
        months_until_birthday = 12 - current_month + birthday_month
        for run in range(months_until_birthday - 1):
            run_month = current_month + (run + 1)
            if run_month > 12:
                run_month = 1
                current_year = current_year + 1
            print("run month debug", run_month)
            days_until_quick_debug = days_till
            days_till = days_till + days_in_month(run_month, current_year)
            print("days in month debug", days_till - days_until_quick_debug)
            print("days until debug", days_till)
        days_till = days_till + birthday_day

    else:
        print("Error.")
        print("Please try again.")
        quit()

    return days_till

Thank you for taking your time to read this and thank you in advance for helping me!
p.s.: I know it is easier to use datetime, but i'm not allowed to import modules.

When I run print(days_till_next_birthday(23,6,11,10,2024)) I get 236 where I expected to get 255. Your debug/print output suggests that it's stuck on calculating january days over and over again after tripping over from december. That is because this code: if run_month > 12: run_month = 1 keeps resetting run_month to 1 because run keeps incrementing over 12.

Hi, thanks for the reply's! @JNevill thank you, but I don't really understand why it can get stuck on January. After running it once, it will add 1 to run_moth using run_month = current_month + (run + 1), in which run will increase by one every run, right?

@JNevil Never mind, I think I understand it now.

As @JNevill pointed out, this loop is the problem:
for run in range(months_until_birthday - 1):
    run_month = current_month + (run + 1)
    if run_month > 12:
        run_month = 1

When run_month exceeds 12, you're setting it back to 1, which is only correct if run_month is exactly 13.  If it's 14 or 15 or 16 etc, you're still setting it back to 1, so every month past 12 is treated as if it were january.
Instead of setting it to 1, you should subtract 12:
    if run_month > 12:
        run_month -= 12

So 14 becomes 2, 15 becomes 3, 16 becomes 4, etc. instead of those all becoming 1.

Thank you very much! It seems to be working correctly now.
